# In TypeScript how do I access the member of an array?

Tags: arrays, typescript

If I have something like:

```
var treeArray: TreesArray;
treeArray = [new tree("Maple"),
    new tree("Pine"),
    new tree("Spruce")];`
```

How do I alert the 2nd member?

This doesn't work: `alert(treeArray[1]);`

**Update:** Sorry, I should have included the full code from the beginning. The alert, as I've written it, still doesn't work.

```
interface ITrees{
    treeName: string;
}

interface TreesArray{
    [index: number]: ITrees;
    length: number;
}

class tree implements ITrees{
    treeName: string;
    constructor (treeName: string){
        this.treeName = treeName; 
    }
}

var treeArray: TreesArray;
treeArray = [new tree("Maple"),
            new tree("Pine"), 
            new tree("Spruce")];

alert(treeArray([1]);//does not alert "Pine"
```

Comment: Why does it not run? It should. Are you sure your scope is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a wrapper (you have called it `TreesArray` in your question), you need to ensure that the wrapper defines an indexer.

```
interface TreesArray {
    [index: number]: tree;
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
class tree{
    constructor(public treeName: string){       
    }
}

interface TreesArray {
    [index: number]: tree;
}

var treeArray: TreesArray;

treeArray = [
    new tree("Maple"),
    new tree("Pine"),
    new tree("Spruce")
];

alert(treeArray[1].treeName);
```

Comment: Steve: I think you and a few others are putting me on the right track. But I still haven't reached a solution. Please see my updated post.

Comment: `treeArray[1]` gives you the whole tree - use `treeArray[1].treeName` to get the name, i.e. Pine.

Answer (score 1):

It does work:

```
class tree{
    constructor(public treename){       
    }
    toString(){return this.treename}
}
var treeArray: tree[];
treeArray = [new tree("Maple"),
        new tree("Pine"),
        new tree("Spruce")];

alert(treeArray[1]);
```

[Try it online by pressing `run`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=class%20tree%7B%0A%09constructor(public%20treename)%7B%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%09toString()%7Breturn%20this.treename%7D%0A%7D%0Avar%20treeArray%3A%20tree%5B%5D%3B%0AtreeArray%20%3D%20%5Bnew%20tree(%22Maple%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20tree(%22Pine%22)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20new%20tree(%22Spruce%22)%5D%3B%0A%09%09%0Aalert(treeArray%5B1%5D)%3B%0A%0A%09%09)

You will get:

[image]